# Фильтрация текста и ссылок

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Нужно получить href и текст из тэга "a" с помощью beautifulsoup

Не знаю как переделать этот код под эту задачу:

```
def main(speed):
    global cycle, url, response, soup
    while True:
        sleep(int(speed))
        url = 'https://freelance.habr.com/tasks?q=python'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        print("<>" * 27)

            #Этот цикл фильтрует всё кроме сылок на объявления
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
            if "/tasks/" in a['href']:
                print("Found the URL:", "https://freelance.habr.com" + a['href'] + "|===")
                a.decompose()
                print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заметил, что у тех ссылок на объявления класс `task__title`, тогда можно пройтись по ним и вытащить ссылки.

А чтобы не составлять вручную абсолютную ссылку использовать `urljoin`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/bd875d9b055b4db140debcacfbc6e58195bd850f/html_parsing/freelance_habr_com__tasks.py)

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://freelance.habr.com/tasks?q=python')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
urls = [
    (urljoin(rs.url, a['href']), a.get_text(strip=True))
    for a in root.select('.task__title > a[href]')
]
print(len(urls), urls)
# 25 [('https://freelance.habr.com/tasks/349695', 'Парсер'), ..., 'Доработка бота Telegram на Python')]
```

Comment: мне нужен вывод и ссылок и текста) а у вас только ссылки

Comment: @nuub228, парсинг самое сложное, а у готовых элементов вытащить текст плевое дело ;) Обновил ответ :)

Comment: видно что самое сложное потому что из твоего кода я ничего не понял)

Comment: @nuub228, если нужно что-то объяснить из моего кода, то не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте :)